# Comparing polynomial and exponential time complexity

Tags: math, big-o

Can anybody please look at the image and tell me how the time is calculated for exponential algorithms i.e., 2^n and 3^n. 
[image: Comparing polynomial and exponential time complexity]

Comment: Algorithms, and Big O Notation, is covered at https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

From the top row, we can see that when n = 10, it takes 10μs to perform the work. That means that each operation takes one microsecond.

The rows with 2<sup>n</sup> and 3<sup>n</sup> are computed by listing 2<sup>n</sup>μs and 3<sup>n</sup>μs in more convenient units. For example, 2<sup>10</sup>μs = 1024μs is about 0.001s.

(It would have been nice for the table designer to explicitly indicate that each operation is one microsecond, since that would let you interpret the data more clearly or adjust it for cases where, say, each operation took one nanosecond.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. The slides should've explicitly mentioned time for each op.